# Host names behind NAT

Tags: nat, hostname

First of all I want to apologize if this is a little bit silly, but I'm getting old..
My topology is as follows:

Internet (I) <-> Router (R) <-> Host (H)

I bought a domain (have a real IP as well) and I want to host a web/mail/ftp server on my local host (H).

How should I set my FQDN for my (R) and for the (H) itself?

How do I set up SSL/TLS Certificate for this topology?

Thank you!

Comment: your domain should be pointing to the device which has the public IP, usually in the description above should be the router. Then you need to create port forwarding rules on the router to point the incoming traffic to you host where the webserver is. That server should have a service (IIS, Apache, Nginx, whatever) that has a virtual host configured with your site and in that configuration you provide the SSL certificate.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. But what should be the exact FQDN (like hostX.mydomain.com) for (R) and (I)?

Answer (score 0):

> What should be the exact FQDN (like `hostX.mydomain.com`) for (R) and (I)?

*Internet (Domain Name/DNS Provider)*

DNS only maps domain names to IPs. So there is effectively no difference between ex.:

```
example.com.        IN A    1.2.3.4
www.example.com.    IN A    1.2.3.4
mail.example.com.   IN A    1.2.3.4
ftp.example.com.    IN A    1.2.3.4
```

In your case, domain name choices likely do not matter much because the IP associated with any of these domains should be the WAN IP of your router or whatever your purchased IP is (ex. `1.2.3.4`).

---

*That said, you should probably have at least `example.com` and `www.example.com` simply because the `www` prefix is so widespread.*

---

*Router*

Your router shouldn't need a specialized FQDN. It just needs to have requests pointed at it (e.g. through whoever hosts your domain name/DNS).

To get traffic to the correct destination on your local network, you simply need to forward the ports you intend to use to the correct local host(s) and let those hosts decide what they want to do with a request for ex. `example.com` versus `sub.example.com` (if anything).

> I want to host a web/mail/ftp server on my local host (H).

Traffic for web, mail and FTP servers typically occurs on separate ports ex.:

- `80`  - HTTP
- `443` - HTTPS
- `25`  - Mail
- `21`  - FTP

With a general set up like the one laid out in your question, there is no need for specialized domain names. Using ex.:

```
example.com:80   (1.2.3.4:80)
example.com:443  (1.2.3.4:443)
example.com:25   (1.2.3.4:25)
example.com:21   (1.2.3.4:21)
```

is possible as long as you have forwarded the correct ports to the correct host(s) via your router (above).

> How do I set up SSL/TLS Certificate for this topology?

Your certificate needs to cover *all* the domain names you intend to use with that certificate. That's it. Any certificates are then installed on the appropriate local host(s).

---

*As a rule of thumb, the minimum domain names you'll  likely want a certificate to support are `example.com` and `www.example.com` for the reasons already given above.*

---

*Wildcard Certificates*

It's probably worth mentioning that some certificate providers can issue "wildcard" certificates where at least one subdomain name is ex. `*.example.com`.

This subdomain covers any subdomain not already listed (which is useful e.g. if subdomains are dynamically created or you simply want to add subdomains later without reissuing the certificate).